# How to insert an empty row when append multiple files in Python

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to loop through all the Json files(they are all in the same format) in a certain path, and extract specific fields from those Json file, append them together and saved as an csv file.

I can achieve my goal via following code:

```
    import pandas as pd   
    import os
    allfiles = os.listdir('.')
    files = [files for files in allfiles if files.endswith('.json')]
    mydata=pd.DataFrame()
    for filename in files:
        #Read Joson File
        df = pd.read_json(filename)
        df=df.loc[:,['col1','col2', 'col3']].set_index('col1')
        mydata=mydata.append(df)
    mydata.to_csv('Result.csv')
```

For example, my original data in two files looks like:

```
       File 1                              File 2       
col1    col2    col3                col1    col2    col3
 A       B        C                   D       E        F
```

The result file from my code gives me(in the 2nd image), however I want to have a break line between those two files(as my Target table) when I append them together, so what should I add to my code in order to make this happens?

```
       My Result                    Target      
col1    col2    col3        col1    col2    col3
   A      B      C             A      B      C
   D      E      F              
                               D      E      F
```

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure if you can append an empty value. You can append NaN by `df.append(pd.Series([np.nan]), ignore_index = True)`

Comment: Like inserting a line between data from different files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add an empty line to a file, just write the newline character '\n'.

In your case, you can try:

after line:

`mydata=mydata.append(df)`

add

`mydata=mydata.append(',,\n')`

So, if you open the csv file with notepad (or some text editor)
you will see:

A,B,C

,,

D,E,F

and in excel, you will see what you want in target above.

Comment: I meet a error:  cannot concatenate object of type "<class 'str'>"; only pd.Series, pd.DataFrame, and pd.Panel (deprecated) objs are valid

Comment: Try creating dataframe with pd.DataFrame([[" ", " ", " "]]) and then append the dataframe.

Comment: I create a df: df1 = pd.DataFrame([[np.nan] * len(df.columns)], columns=df.columns,index=df.index.unique()); then mydata=mydata.append(df)
    mydata=mydata.append(df1); and this is working. thanks